# How to set up Alfresco Share behind apache reverse proxy

Tags: tomcat, alfresco

I've been looking for how to do this properly through the Alfresco docs, and am not having any luck...

How the heck do you set up Alfresco Share to work from behind an Apache reverse proxy?

(I'm running CentOS 6.x)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are hosting Alfresco in a Tomcat container and assuming you have enabled the AJP protocol in that Tomcat instance (recommended) on the default port in Tomcat's `server.xml`, something like the following should work.

```
ProxyPass /alfresco ajp://localhost:8009/alfresco
ProxyPassReverse /alfresco ajp://localhost:8009/alfresco

ProxyPass /share ajp://localhost:8009/share
ProxyPassReverse /share ajp://localhost:8009/share

<Location /alfresco/webdav/ >
    <Limit OPTIONS PROPFIND GET REPORT MKACTIVITY PROPPATCH PUT CHECKOUT MKCOL MOVE COPY DELETE LOCK UNLOCK MERGE>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Satisfy Any
    </Limit>
</Location>

RedirectMatch ^/$ /share/
```

You should not need to do anything else on the Alfresco/Share side although you may want to set the correct host/port values in your `alfresco-global.properties` file. Update the properties `alfresco.host`, `alfresco.port`, `share.host` and `share.port`.